# R - List files from directory except a pattern

Tags: r

I am using the following code for listing files from an specific directory:

```
p<-"my_path"
dir(p)

 [1] "00_Iniciar.r"                 "01_01_Carga_diario.r"         "01_Carga_continuos.r"        
 [4] "02_01_Carga_intervenciones.r" "02_02_Carga_young.r"          "02_03_Carga_hrsd.r"          
 [7] "02_Carga_discretos.r"         "03_Carga_eventos.r"           "04_graficos.r"               
[10] "0x_bin.r"                     "desktop.ini"                  "graficos"
```

How can I list all of them except "desktop.ini" using "pattern" parameter?.

Thanks

Comment: `x = dir(p); x[x != "desktop.ini"]`

Comment: `filesp <- dir(p); filesp[!filesp %in% c("desktop.ini")]`

Answer (score 4):

Using `grep` like this can also do it:

```
grep(dir(p), pattern = "^desktop\\.ini$", value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
```

Setting `value = TRUE` makes `grep` return the values corresponding to `pattern` matches. Furthermore, `invert = TRUE` makes `grep` return all values for non-hits.

Alternatively

```
grep(dir(p), pattern = "desktop.ini", value = TRUE, invert = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
```

is equivalent as pointed out by @dww in the comments.

A demonstration that works follows. Exclude all `.html` files found in the base package library;

```
grep(dir(system.file(), recursive = TRUE), 
     pattern = "\\.html$", value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
# [1] "CITATION"              "demo/error.catching.R" "demo/is.things.R"      "demo/recursion.R"     
# [5] "demo/scoping.R"        "DESCRIPTION"           "help/aliases.rds"      "help/AnIndex"         
# [9] "help/base.rdb"         "help/base.rdx"         "help/paths.rds"        "html/R.css"           
#[13] "INDEX"                 "Meta/demo.rds"         "Meta/features.rds"     "Meta/hsearch.rds"     
#[17] "Meta/links.rds"        "Meta/package.rds"      "Meta/Rd.rds"           "R/base"               
#[21] "R/base.rdb"            "R/base.rdx"            "R/Rprofile"
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution.. but I think it can be improved..

```
dir(p,pattern="^([^d]|d[^e]|de[^s]|des[^k]|desk[^t]|deskt[^o]|deskto[^p])")
```